# The PTS value of the live streaming package is abnormal

Tags: c++, qt, video, ffmpeg

I am using the ffmpeg source code to receive the udp network video stream, but there is a problem with this video stream. Occasionally, the audio and video packets dts and pts jump at the same time, that is, from a large value to a difference of dozens of times. Very small value, I want to use a solution to solve this problem in the code, but can't think of it. Hope you can help me, thanks!

The following is a process of writing to the buffer to be decoded after receiving the video packet when I receive the network stream. The decoding is done by the video decoding thread, which is only responsible for receiving the stream and writing the buffer to be decoded.

```
    //read video package
    if(pAvPacket->stream_index == pThis->m_iVideoStreamIndex)
    {
        std::cout<<"Video_Packet_DTS: "<<pAvPacket->dts<<"   Video_Packet_PTS: "<<pAvPacket->pts<<std::endl;
        
         //Video frame rate assignment
        if(pThis->m_pVideoTimeBase->num > 0 && pAvPacket->duration > 0)
            pThis->m_iVideoFPS = (pThis->m_pVideoTimeBase->den / pThis->m_pVideoTimeBase->num) / pAvPacket->duration;

        if(pThis->m_iDecodeMode == DECODE_MODE_ONLY_CURRENT_COLLECTION)
            pThis->m_videoDecodeThreadState = THREAD_NEED_STOP;     //stop the thread
        else
            pThis->m_videoDecodeThreadState = THREAD_NEED_RUN;      //make the thread run

        if(pThis->m_iMultiMediaType != MULTI_MEDIA_TYPE_FILE
                && pAvPacket->flags == AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY)
        {
                pThis->m_bIsFindIFrame = YTRUE;
        }

        VideoFramesCount ++;
        pThis->m_iReadVideoPacketCount ++;
        if(pThis->m_iDecodeMode != DECODE_MODE_ONLY_CHECK_NET && pThis->m_iDecodeMode != DECODE_MODE_AUDIO && pThis->m_bIsFindIFrame)
            YGlobCircleBufferWrite<AVPacket *>(pThis->m_videoPacketBuffer, &pAvPacket, 1);
        else
            av_packet_unref(pAvPacket);
        pAvPacket = YNULL;
    }
```

The following is the information printed when the code is run:

```
Video_Packet_DTS: 8590470992   Video_Packet_PTS: 8590470992
Video_Packet_DTS: 8590474592   Video_Packet_PTS: 8590474592
Video_Packet_DTS: 8590478192   Video_Packet_PTS: 8590478192
Video_Packet_DTS: 8590481792   Video_Packet_PTS: 8590481792
Video_Packet_DTS: 550800   Video_Packet_PTS: 550800
Video_Packet_DTS: 554400   Video_Packet_PTS: 554400
Video_Packet_DTS: 558000   Video_Packet_PTS: 558000
Video_Packet_DTS: 561600   Video_Packet_PTS: 561600
Video_Packet_DTS: 565200   Video_Packet_PTS: 565200
```

and the error message is printed:

```
[h264 @ 04fea380] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 04fea380] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 04fea380] no frame!
[swscaler @ 19b04600] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speed loss
[mp3float @ 04feadc0] overread, skip -6 enddists: -2 -2
[mpegts @ 04fcbf40] DTS 550800 < 8590481792 out of order
[mp3float @ 04feadc0] overread, skip -7 enddists: -6 -6
[mp3float @ 04feadc0] overread, skip -5 enddists: -2 -2
```

I am so obsessed with their pts because when I synchronize audio and video, I will use their pts for synchronization. If the pts are too different, the video will be stuck when playing the video. I don't know how to avoid

Comment: If you're using MPEG-TS on input then the timestamps will wrap-around each ~26.5 hours (33 bits, 90 kHz clock).

Comment: It turned out to be the case. At present, my method is to delete the old package and use the new package directly when this happens.